# Azure Machine Learning SDK V1 migration to V2 Pipeline Steps

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk, azure-ml-pipelines

I am trying to migrate Pipelines from Azure Machine Learning SDK V1 to V2, but sometimes I don't understand the logic behind the V2 and I get stuck.

In V1, I just had to create PythonScriptStep and wrap it into a StepSequence and deploy the pipeline. My scripts are simple, no input, no outputs. We store data in ADLS Gen2 and use databricks tables as inputs. This is why I don't have any inputs/outputs.

```
script_step_1 = PythonScriptStep(
    name="step1",
    script_name="main.py",
    arguments=arguments, # list of PipelineParameter
    compute_target=ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name="cpu-16-128"),
    source_directory="./my_project_folder",
    runconfig=runconfig, # Conda + extra index url + custom dockerfile
    allow_reuse=False,
)

script_step_2 = PythonScriptStep(
    name="step2",
    ...
)

step_sequence = StepSequence(
    steps=[
        script_step_1,
        script_step_2,
    ]
)

# Create Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(
    workspace=ws,
    steps=step_sequence,
)

pipeline_run = experiment.submit(pipeline)
```

With V2, we need to create a "node" in a component that will be use by a pipeline.

I've made my Environment with dockerfile with BuildContext, and feed a representation of requirements.txt to a conda environment dictionary where I added my extra index url.

```
azureml_env = Environment(
    build=BuildContext(
        path="./docker_folder", # With Dockerfile and requirements.txt
    ),
    name="my-project-env",
)
```

Now I make a command component that will invoke python and a script with some arguments:

```
step_1 = command(
       environment=azureml_env ,
       command="python main.py",
       code="./my_project_folder",
   )
```

Now that I have my step1 and step2 in SDK V2, I have no clue on how to make a sequence without Input/Output

```
@pipeline(compute="serverless")
def default_pipeline():
    return {
        "my_pipeline": [step_1, step_2]
    }
```

I can not manage to make the `pipeline` work to make a basic run a 2 consecutive steps.

I guess after I manage to get this right, I can create/update the pipeline like this:

```
my_pipeline = default_pipeline()


# submit the pipeline job
pipeline_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    my_pipeline,
    experiment_name=experiment_name,
)
```

UPDATE 1:

Tried to create my own `StepSequence` (very naive) with dummies input/outputs

```
class CommandSequence:
    def __init__(self, commands, ml_client):
        self.commands = commands
        self.ml_client = ml_client

    def build(self):
        for i in range(len(self.commands)):
            cmd = self.commands[i]
            if i == 0:
                cmd = command(
                    display_name=cmd.display_name,
                    description=cmd.description,
                    environment=cmd.environment,
                    command=cmd.command,
                    code=cmd.code,
                    is_deterministic=cmd.is_deterministic,
                    outputs=dict(
                        my_output=Output(type="uri_folder", mode="rw_mount"),
                    ),
                )
            else:
                cmd = command(
                    display_name=cmd.display_name,
                    description=cmd.description,
                    environment=cmd.environment,
                    command=cmd.command,
                    code=cmd.code,
                    is_deterministic=cmd.is_deterministic,
                    inputs=self.commands[i - 1].outputs.my_output,
                    outputs=dict(
                        my_output=Output(type="uri_folder", mode="rw_mount"),
                    ),
                )
            cmd = self.ml_client.create_or_update(cmd.component)
            self.commands[i] = cmd
            print(self.commands[i])

        return self.commands
```

I had to recreate `command` because they protected a lot of stuff in the object...

```
@pipeline(compute="serverless")
def default_pipeline():
    command_sequence = CommandSequence([step_1, step_2], ml_client).build()
    return {
        "my_pipeline": command_sequence[-1].outputs.my_output
    }
```

But it fails to link the output of step 1 to input of step 2.

> inputs=self.commands[i - 1].outputs.my_output,
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'my_output'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own tools to recreate something that can acheive the same output.

I build a graph of steps (commands or node in Azure language) and then get the dependecy order of this graph and build the pipeline. This methods fits if you want to create a pipeline with sequencial or parallel steps. Which means, no custom Inputs/Outputs like Azure Machine Learning forces us to use to define the worflow logic. Some people, like me, just want to execute step 1 before step 2 with no data passing between them because the data is stored in a Database or a Azure Storage.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List
import random
import string

from azure.ai.ml import Input, Output, command
from azure.ai.ml.dsl import pipeline
from azure.ai.ml.entities import BuildContext, Environment


class StepsGraph:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize a StepsGraph instance to manage step dependencies.

        The StepsGraph uses an ordered dictionary to store steps and their dependencies.
        """
        self.steps = OrderedDict()

    def add_edges(self, step_1, step_2):
        """
        Add a dependency relationship between two steps.

        Args:
            step_1: The first step.
            step_2: The step that depends on the first step.
        """
        if step_1 not in self.steps:
            self.steps[step_1] = []
        if step_2 not in self.steps:
            self.steps[step_2] = []
        self.steps[step_1].append(step_2)

    def get_dependency(self):
        """
        Get the steps in the order of their dependencies.

        Returns:
            List: A list of steps in the order they need to be executed to satisfy all dependencies.
        """

        def dfs(node, visited, result):
            visited[node] = True
            if node in self.steps:
                for neighbor in self.steps[node]:
                    if not visited[neighbor]:
                        dfs(neighbor, visited, result)
            result.append(node)

        visited = {step: False for step in self.steps}
        result = []

        for step in self.steps:
            if not visited[step]:
                dfs(step, visited, result)

        return result[::-1]

    def get_parents(self, step):
        """
        Get the steps that are dependent on a given step.

        Args:
            step: The step to find dependent steps for.

        Returns:
            List: A list of steps that depend on the given step.
        """
        parents = []
        for s, connections in self.steps.items():
            if step in connections:
                parents.append(s)
        return parents

    def print_steps(self):
        for step, edges in self.steps.items():
            print(f"Step {step} -> {edges}")


def create_input(step):
    """
    Create an input dictionary for a step.

    Args:
        step (str): The name of the step for which to create an input.

    Returns:
        dict: A dictionary representing the input for the specified step with the following structure:
            {step: Input(type="uri_folder", mode="rw_mount")}
    """
    return {f"{step}": Input(type="uri_folder", mode="rw_mount")}


def create_output(step):
    """
    Create an output dictionary for a step.

    Args:
        step (str): The name of the step for which to create an output.

    Returns:
        dict: A dictionary representing the output for the specified step with the following structure:
            {step: Output(type="uri_folder", mode="rw_mount")}
    """
    return {f"{step}": Output(type="uri_folder", mode="rw_mount")}


def create_pipeline(steps_graph, default_compute, name, experiment_name):
    """
    Create a pipeline with specified steps and dependencies.

    Args:
        steps_graph (Step or StepsGraph): A Step or StepsGraph object representing the steps and their dependencies in the pipeline.
            If a Step is provided, it will be treated as a standalone step.
        default_compute: The default compute target for the pipeline (or None for serverless execution).
        name (str): The name of the pipeline.
        experiment_name (str): The name of the experiment associated with the pipeline.

    Returns:
        Callable: A callable function representing the created pipeline.

    Raises:
        ValueError: If `name` or `experiment_name` is not provided.

    Note:
        - The `steps_graph` argument can be a single Step or a StepsGraph object.
        - The pipeline's structure is determined by the dependencies defined in the `steps_graph`.
        - The pipeline is created as a Python function and can be executed when called.

    Example:
        # Create a pipeline with specific steps and dependencies

        steps_graph = StepsGraph()
        step1 = Step(...)
        step2 = Step(...)
        step3 = Step(...)

        steps_graph.add_edges(step_1, step_2)
        steps_graph.add_edges(step_2, step_3)
        steps_graph.add_edges(step_2, step_4)
        steps_graph.add_edges(step_2, step_6)
        steps_graph.add_edges(step_4, step_5)
        steps_graph.add_edges(step_3, step_7)
        steps_graph.add_edges(step_6, step_7)
        steps_graph.add_edges(step_5, step_7)

        pipeline_job = create_pipeline(steps_graph, default_compute="my_compute", name="my_pipeline", experiment_name="my_experiment")
    """
    # default_compute = None => Serverless
    if not name:
        raise ValueError("Please provide a `name` for your pipeline.")
    if not experiment_name:
        raise ValueError("Please provide an `experiment_name` for your pipeline.")

    @pipeline(
        default_compute=default_compute,
        name=experiment_name,
        experiment_name=experiment_name,
    )
    def default_pipeline():
        if isinstance(steps_graph, Step):
            steps_graph.build()()
            return
        dependency_oder = steps_graph.get_dependency()
        command_dict = {}
        parent_dict = {}

        for step, edges in steps_graph.steps.items():
            print(f"Step {step} -> {edges}")
            parent_dict[str(step)] = steps_graph.get_parents(step)

        print(f"parent_dict : {parent_dict}")
        print(f"dependency_oder: {dependency_oder}")
        for step in dependency_oder:
            print(f"step : {step}")
            inputs_dict = {}
            step.update_link(
                outputs=create_output(step),
            )
            for parent_node in reversed(parent_dict[str(step)]):
                step.update_link(
                    inputs=create_input(parent_node),
                )
                custom_output = getattr(
                    command_dict[str(parent_node)].outputs, str(parent_node)
                )
                input_name = list(parent_node.outputs.keys())[
                    0
                ]  # Because we know we have only one output per steps
                inputs_dict[input_name] = custom_output

            print(inputs_dict)

            for key, value in inputs_dict.items():
                print(key, value._port_name)

            print(step.inputs)
            command_dict[str(step)] = step.build()(**inputs_dict)

    return default_pipeline()


def generate_custom_uuid(length=8, parts=4):
    custom_uuid = ""
    for _ in range(parts):
        part = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=length))
        custom_uuid += part + "_"

    custom_uuid = custom_uuid[:-1]
    return custom_uuid


class Step:
    """
    Represents a step in a StepsGraph.

    This class is used to define and manage the properties of a step,
    including its inputs and outputs. It provides methods for updating
    the input and output links and for building the step's command.

    Attributes:
        inputs (dict): A dictionary of input values for the step.
        outputs (dict): A dictionary of output values for the step.

    Methods:
        __init__(self, **kwargs): Initializes a Step object with optional
            keyword arguments to set initial properties.
        __str__(self): Returns a string representation of the step.
        update_link(self, inputs=None, outputs=None): Updates the input and
            output links with the provided dictionaries.
        build(self): Builds and returns the command for executing the step.

    Example usage:
    >>> my_step = Step(name="Sample Step", inputs={"input_1": "value1"})
    >>> my_step.update_link(outputs={"output_1": "result"})
    >>> command = my_step.build()
    >>> # Then you need to call the command to build the inputs/outputs. Use `create_pipeline` for this.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.inputs = None
        self.outputs = None
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self.uuid = self.display_name + "_" + generate_custom_uuid()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uuid

    def update_link(self, inputs=None, outputs=None):
        if self.inputs and inputs:
            self.inputs.update(inputs)
        elif inputs:
            self.inputs = inputs
        if self.outputs and outputs:
            self.outputs.update(outputs)
        elif outputs:
            self.outputs = outputs

    def build(self):
        return command(**self.__dict__)
```

Basically `Step` can get the same arguments as the `command` function from `azure.ai.ml.command`
Here is how I use it:

```
step_1 = Step(
    display_name="step_1",
    description="step_1",
    environment=...,
    command="python main.py",
    code...,
    is_deterministic=False,
    environment_variables=...,
)
step_2 = Step(...)
step_3 = Step(...)
step_4 = Step(...)
step_5 = Step(...)
step_6 = Step(...)
step_7 = Step(...)

steps_graph = StepsGraph()
steps_graph.add_edges(step_1, step_2)
steps_graph.add_edges(step_2, step_3)
steps_graph.add_edges(step_2, step_4)
steps_graph.add_edges(step_2, step_6)
steps_graph.add_edges(step_4, step_5)
steps_graph.add_edges(step_3, step_7)
steps_graph.add_edges(step_6, step_7)
steps_graph.add_edges(step_5, step_7)

pipeline_job = create_pipeline(steps_graph, default_compute="my_compute", name="my_pipeline", experiment_name="my_experiment")

pipeline_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(pipeline_job)
print(pipeline_job) # To get URL in terminal, or you can play with it for schedules
```

Here is the output for this example:
[image: AML_SDK_V2_Pipeline]

Comment: I'm curious why didn't you want to just pass the blob directory path as an input to your components?  For example, like in this tutorial - https://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/aml-command/

Comment: Good question, I know it is possible, but I made a python package with all the configuration inside to connect to ADLS Gen2/Databricks/CosmosDB/ADF. I could added a Integer Input/output, for my purpose, it doesn't change anything. I just wanted a "fake" link between each steps to create a DAG. I think if you look at StepSequence in SDK V1, it creates also dummy links with random input/output names. But clearly you can update this code to your needs

Comment: Makes sense, seems like your solution works.  I'm not familiar with SDK V1 and in fact one of the recommendations from that blog is to bypass this question of SDK syntax altogether by using CLI syntax for the pipeline construction where possible.  It helps to avoid these issues when the Python syntax is updated.  It's also more succinct.

Comment: hi @BeGreen, I am wondering how would this integrate with a sweep job. We have a training pipeline with three steps i. training, metric_adjustment and register_model. The training step has to be a sweep job. I am trying your solution but cant figure out how do I integrate this.

Comment: I'm no expert in the package. But from i've read on the documentation. Sweep is a method called on `command`. So I guess you could modify the `Step.build` method. And do something like `return command(**self.__dict__).sweep(**self.sweep_parameters)` and you can try to add a new argument at `Step`
Note: `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` will get `command` and `sweep` parameters inside your `command`.

step_1 = Step(
    display_name="step_1",
    ....
    sweep_parameters = { "sampling_algorithm" = "random", ....} 
)

Comment: Hi @BeGreen,

I have similar. Using command component. so my steps were like this: ´step1=command(...arguments....).components(argument=value,....)´

with your solution, I added is_sweep, sweep_properties to the Step class. Complains if input is not provided so, I have added method to the Step configure_inputs(self, **kwargs): self.input_configuration=kwargs

and configure_sweep(self):
cmd_step = command(**self.__dict__).sweep(...)
cmd_step.set_limits(...)
return command_step

Comment: @BeGreen

The build method is also changed:
command_dict[str(step)] = step.build().component(**step.input_configuration)(**inputs_dict)

But when I run pipeline it gives error:

File "/home/vsts/work/1/s/ml_service/utils/pipeline_builder.py", line 183, in default_pipeline
    step.update_link(
TypeError: '_AttrDict' object is not callable

It seems the step is converted to command.sweep type and that is not callable at this line:
step.update_link(
                outputs=create_output(step),
  )

I am not sure, still experimenting.

Comment: @BeGreen would be thankful if we can have discussion around it and find a solution. Would it be okay if I create a new question on StackOverflow?

Comment: @BeGreen

I have added aniother question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77542089/azure-machine-learning-sdk-v2-sequencing-pipeline-steps

WOuld be thankful if you could help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Pipeline SDK v2 documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/how-to-use-pipeline-component.md), it seems that the pipeline component in V2 requires explicit definition of inputs/outputs.
And unlike SDK v1, it doesn't have [StepSequence Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.stepsequence?view=azure-ml-py) functionality at the moment.

However, since your scripts don't have any explicit inputs/outputs, one possible workaround can be by using a dummy output just to satisfy the pipeline component requirements and maintain step sequence.

Below is pseudo code:

```py
step_1 = command(
environment=azureml_env,
command="python step1.py",
code="./my_project_folder",
outputs=dummy_output
)
step_2 = command(
environment=azureml_env,
command="python step2.py",
code="./my_project_folder",
inputs=dummy_output,
outputs=dummy_output2
)
```

Comment: This is indeed what I tried. I made my own `StepSequence` class, but it stills fails to create a working `pipeline`. I will update my post for the code/error